# MPAndroidChart use getPixelForValues correctly to gradient color a chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linear-gradients

I'm trying to set the color gradient of a `LineChart` based on its `y` value following [this issue](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3977). Plan is to make one gradient that coverts the whole thing only once.

```
   override fun createChartGradient(myEntities: List<MyEntity>, chart: LineChart): LinearGradient {
       val transformer = Transformer(chart.viewPortHandler)
       val entries: List<Entry> = createEntriesFrom(myEntities) // this works fine, the chart is plotted alright
       val pixelXValues = entries.map { transformer.getPixelForValues(it.x, it.y).x.toFloat() }.toFloatArray()
       val colors = calculateColorsBasedOnValues(myEntities) // this works fine, I can set the fill color of points with this. 
       return LinearGradient(pixelXValues.first(), 0f, pixelXValues.last(), 0f, colors.toIntArray(), pixelXValues.lerp(), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT)
   }

   private fun FloatArray.lerp(): FloatArray {
       val total = this.last() - this.first()
       return this.map { ((it - this.first()) / total) }.toFloatArray()
   }
```

Which is the assigned to the chart like

```
    val gradient = lineChartService.createChartGradient(entities, chart)
    chart.renderer.paintRender.shader = gradient
```

I'm well aware that I'll have to update this on zooming in or out but for now I struggle to make it work even with completely zoomed out, in which case the chart seems to repeat the shader 5 times - but based on my calculations I should cover the whole thing exactly once.

I attached a debugger and the `lerp` function's output is from 0 to 1, inclusive.

What am I doing wrong with `getPixelForValues` or the `LinearGradient`?